# Is it possible to create Android App Bundle (aab) for Google play with Wolfram language/Mathematica?

Tags: manipulate, game, web, webtools

Mathematica is excellent tool but I don't know if is it  possible to create Android App Bundle (aab) for Google play with Wolfram language/Mathematica or not?
Please advise or share your opinion/idea for this.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this bundle? Distribute a copy of Mathematica to use? Almost certainly _impractical_. Not necessarily impossible, but the bundle would be massive and licensing would be a nightmare

Comment: @b3m2a1 thank you. I rent a webpage and use https://appsgeyser.com to convert the webpage to the Android App Bundle (AAB) to upload in the "Google play" so everyone can use the app to look information instead of searching on the web (people can open phone to use the app, they don't remember webpage). The problem is there is some errors that appsgeyser.com can't solve. The rent website can't modify and add more options, e.g compare price with others. The best for me is to make the web by myself and use the Mathematica tools to handle the options as well as convert to the AAB file. Please advise

Comment: that's much more feasible (although likely not prebuilt). If you provide more details about what you're trying to do and some sample data people are more likely to help

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. I first want to use WL/Mathematica to create Android App Bundle (AAB) for this example merrymart.asia to upload in the "Google play". The appsgeyser.com can't solve some problem when upload the AAB to the Google play. Secondly more complicate is to made an own app (similar/identical to the merrymart.asia). The app should be able to find and compare price from other web, such as amazon.com, with the problem here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257411/how-to-use-webexecute-to-check-the-checkbox-and-to-select-the-item-in-dropdown-l  . Please advise me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Inc. changes this concept rather often but since some time the API are gathered into the Wolfram Alpha Pro product. The central page for product information is https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/. The learning path doing this is harder than coping with Wolfram Alpha Pro. You have to work rapidly with the Google Android API. The start is always on the Google Play Store and then make Yourself a Google Android Developer taking the Google course path to obey their strict app requirement policies and security policies.

From both starting points this community may not be the very best starting point. Seems a new topic. All the best.

The given link allows detailed API searches for the type of apps that are reasonable to  Wolfram Inc. For example on [Intelligent Assistent](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/documentation/) they show API Rest code that is central to this type of Intelligent Assistant with Wolfram Alpha Pro. Like Google Developer API they work with templates that allow only for specialized and strongly typed app skeletons. Nevertheless, this may lead to very rich and nice adopted apps.

You can not go around making Yourself a Google Play Store Developer for broad Android purposes. To get on the faster learning track and not to spend too much money on App hosting and SEO capabilities far beyond the Google [Android](https://developers.google.com/android) package head to MIT [Appinventor](https://appinventor.mit.edu/). These offer a free-of-charge entry level for developing a first-level stub to upload on the Google Play Store.

Google offers free education Android developers too: [Google Grow](https://grow.google/androiddev/#?modal_active=none). The Wolfram Inc. part of Your project plan make Yourself an account on [Wolfram Alpha Deveolper Portal](https://account.wolfram.com/login/oauth2/sign-in).